# Prove for $ x_i≧0 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0 $ then $ x_1=x_2=x_3=x_n=0 $ with only the definition of real number

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove for $ x_i≧0 \, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0  $ then $ x_1=x_2=x_3........=x_n=0 $ with only the definition of real number.

cite:

Axiom R1.

$ \mathbf R $ is a field—that is, there exist
a binary operation $ (x, y) \mapsto x + y $ of addition on $ \mathbf R $,

a binary operation $ (x, y) \mapsto xy $ of multiplication on $ \mathbf R $,

distinguished elements 0 (zero) and 1 (one) of $\mathbf R $, with $0 \neq 1,$

a unary operation $ x \mapsto −x $ (negation) on $ \mathbf R$ , and

a unary operation $ x \mapsto x^{−1} $ of reciprocation, or inversion, on $\mathbf R $ \ {0}

such that for all $x, y, z ∈ \mathbf R $,

$ x + y = y + x$ ,

$ (x + y) + z = x + (y + z) $ ,

$0 + x = x$ ,

$x + (−x) = 0$ ,

$xy = yx$ ,

$(xy) z = x (yz) $ ,

$x(y + z) = xy + xz$ ,

$1x = x$, and

$xx^{−1}=1  $ if $ x \neq 0. $

Axioms R2.

$\mathbf R$ is endowed with a total partial order $≥$ (greater than
or equal to), and hence an associated strict partial order $>$ (greater than),
such that

• if $x ≥ y$, then $x + z ≥ y + z$, and

• if $x ≥ 0$ and $y ≥ 0$, then $xy ≥ 0$.

Axiom R3.

The *least–upper–bound principle*: if a nonempty subset $S$ of
$\mathbf R$ is bounded above relative to the relation $≥$, then it has a (unique) least
upper bound.

Comment: Write your definition of the real numbers. Also, proof by contradiction is probably the easiest, i.e. assume some $x_j > 0$ and show that the sum must be positive then.

Answer (score 2):

We can use induction. For $n=1$, this is obviously true. Now, let use have $k$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^kx_i = 0 \implies x_1=x_2=...=x_k=0, x_i \ge0$$
Now, we analyse the statement for $k+1$ reals
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}x_i = 0, x_i\ge 0$$
$$\implies \sum_1^kx_i + x_{k+1} = 0$$

Now , from our induction step, we have
$$\sum_i^k x_i = 0, x_i = 0$$
$$\implies x_{k+1} = 0$$
Hence proved using induction

Comment: but the condition given is that  x_i only≧0 not =0.

Comment: Yeah, but my induction step assumes that this is true till k, and then I show that forces $x_{k+1}$ to be $0$

Comment: The only properties of $\Bbb R$ that are needed are that $(\Bbb R, +, 0,>)$ is an ordered group..............+1.

Answer (score 0):

Because the transitive property of total partial order on $\mathbf R$ so $x \ge y  $ and $a\ge b$ means $x+a \ge y+b$ .

So for $x_i \ge0$ , $x_{i_1}+x_{i_2} \ge0 $ for all $x_i$ .

so $x_2+x_3+x_4+........+x_n\ge0=\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_i$

so $x_2+x_3+x_4+........+x_n+-x_2+-x_3+-x_4........+-x_n \ge \sum^{n}_{i=1}x_i +-x_2+-x_3+-x_4........+-x_n$

so $0\ge x_1$ and by antisymmetric $0=x_1$.

And proceed acorrdingly throughout $x_n$.

Comment: after some thinking i get it.